# Calling function2(x) from a function1(x) passing the same argument class?

Tags: python, function, class

```
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self, firstVar):
        '''
        Some docstring
        '''
        self.var = firstVar


    def myProcedure1(self, secondVar):
        '''
        Some docstring1
        '''
        return my_thing

    def myProcedure(self, secondVar):
        '''
        Some docstring2
        '''

        what_I_Need = myClass.myProcedure1(secondVar)
        do something with this
        return something else
```

When I call `myClass_instance.myProcedure(secondVar)` I get a error saying that:

```
TypeError: myProcedure1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'secondVar'
```

How can I pass `secondVar` to make this work?

Comment: This is a rather rudimentary question, though I can't find an existing answer on SO!  You have to construct an instance of the class to call an instance method.

Comment: So what is u'r point??? I did search for the answer and it was not in SO questions!!! Does it mean that only 'experts' like YOU your Highness can ask questions on SO? Why dont u make your knowledge useful to others(like others made it to you when u were a rookie in programing) instead of playing the Almighty. And if you are so good why do other programmers that have 59+ times your reputation took the time to answer. U think u are a so good but u r just a little..... something. And still your answer is SO WRONG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the method directly on the class, which is *unbound*. That means no `self` is passed in, and `secondVar` is interpreted as the value for `self` instead.

Call the method *on `self`*:

```
self.myProcedure1(secondVar)
```

`self` here is just another reference to the instance, just like `myClass_instance` is when you call `myProceduce(...)` on that object.